# Firebase stuff of My Nextjs App doesn't work after the success deployment to Vercel

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vercel

my gorgeous friend on the Internet!!

So, I could successfully deploy my next.js + Firebase web app to Vercel. I saw the congratulation screen. Then, I jumped to the real website, and it showed properly. Because users need to log in to use an app, I clicked a login button that functions Google auth. However, it doesn't show a login popup that appeared when building this app.

I doubt the security rules on the Firebase console. I haven't changed anything (like test mode to production) on the console. The app was totally fine on localhost.

This is my app deployed on Vercel.
https://kibun-up.vercel.app/

Please click the login button in the Header to see if it's not working.

It's my first time deploying and building an app with Next.js and Firebase.

Also, I have some Firebase environment variables. I added them all when deployed to Vercel, which turned into a successful deployment.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: You should also show the [complete minimal code that reproduces the problem](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example) in your question. Do not link to the application - show us the code and explain what's not working the way you expect.